# How to Make File Description Field Required?

Tags: files

Use case: Users who are authorized to use the edit page are required

1. To upload at least one file
2. Must have an associated description with the file.

Plus: How can I edit "Description" to display "Alternative File Name" ?

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: What module are you using for this?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your needs, this could be accomplished using [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), adding an image field and a description field (which can be made required) to the collection:

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
>   embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
>   viewed and edited separately too.